# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: Modelo.Proveedores.getNombre

Tags: java, mysql, mysqlconnector

[image: Estoy intentando hacer un sistema de ventas que conecta con MySQL, pero al momento de insertar los datos o consultar me lanza la siguiente exception:AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException y me da error en estas partes del codigo: cannot be applied to given types]

```
try
        {
        ps = (PreparedStatement) conexion.prepareStatement(" select * from Proveedor where nombre=?");
        ps.setString(1, proveedor.getNombre());
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next())
        {
            proveedor.getNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
            proveedor.getApellidos(rs.getString("apellidos"));
            proveedor.getDireccion(rs.getString("direccion"));
            proveedor.getTelefono(rs.getString("telefono"));
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        
        
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.err.println("Error, "+ex);
        return false;
    }



    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       if(e.getSource()==interfaz.insertar_p)
       {
           proveedor.getNombre(interfaz.txtnombre_p.getText());
           proveedor.getApellidos(interfaz.txtapellidos_p.getText());
           proveedor.getDireccion(interfaz.txtdireccion_p.getText());
           proveedor.getTelefono(interfaz.txttelefono_p.getText());
           
           if(consulta.insertar(proveedor))
           {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los datos fueron insertados correctamente");
           }
           else
           {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al insertar los datos");
           }
           
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.